# cakephp: update related belogsTo table

Tags: cakephp, model-associations

I am updating my Retailer Model which belongsTo Address Model, when I create new record it easily create new row for address and insert its key on Retailer Model:

> View:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Retailer');
echo $this->Form->input('Name');
echo $this->Form->input('Address.add_line1');
echo $this->Form->input('Address.add_line2');
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

> Model (Retailer):

```
public $belongsTo = 'Address';
```

> RetailersController->add()

```
$this->Retailer->create();
$this->Retailer->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

However When I tried to update Retailer the Retailer Model updated but insted of updating previous Address record it creates new record and puts its key on Retailer table:

```
RetailersController->edit($id = null)
$this->Retailer->id = $id;
$this->Retailer->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

I also tried this but not working :

```
RetailersController->edit($id = null)
$post = $this->Retailer->findById($id);
$this->Retailer->id = $id;
$this->request->data['Retailer']['address_id'] = $post['Retailer']['address_id'];
$this->Retailer->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to tell it the id of the address.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Address.id');
```

Otherwise it will perform an create, as you said.

Comment: Thanks it's working for me although I put the value of Address id in Controller instead of view:- `$this->request->data['Address']['id'] = $post['Retailer']['address_id']`